# How to find registrador of DS record

Tags: dnssec

I bought a domain name magicescape.es a year ago. The issue is that this domain name has a DS record, but I didn't add it and can't delete or change. For .es domains, DNSSEC does not support. I spent a lot of time with the support of Godaddy and the last answer was "we can't help you with DS record because we don't see it. You should ask old website hosting to delete all related to this website content". But how it can affect the domain name that has different NS records?
I can see DS record here [dns-analyzer](https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/magicescape.es).
Is there a way to find where from this particular DS record?

Comment: Is Godaddy your domain name registrar? as you can configure Ds here https://ph.godaddy.com/help/add-a-ds-record-23865 but i am not sure about .es domain

Comment: @svikramjeet Yes, my registrar is GoDaddy, but I can't change DS records because for .es domains it's not possible.

Comment: The link you shared is showing DS records for different es domain so tld is responsible for this and you can't do anything.

Comment: @svikramjeet Why you think that it's a different domain? I checked twice and it' the same https://ibb.co/M9dGtTD

Comment: i mean every es domain is showing same DS records https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/hello.es

Comment: @svikramjeet look at the down of your report - "No DS records found for hello.es in the es zone" and in my "Found 1 DS records for magicescape.es in the es zone".

Comment: 1, Yes your domain has one DS record which seems to be root level record
2. not only .es but  all country-specific domain like .au, .in etc are not allowed to update DS in godaddy.
3. Your NS are still not poitning to godaddy (wix at the moment) so you can check after reverting if godaddy can help you

Comment: @svikramjeet Thank you for this information, but I don't understand how pointing my NS records can help with DS record that can't be modified?

Comment: I forgot to mention that DS record restriction is just on GoDaddy end this is not global or DNS restriction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218382/discussion-between-dzam-and-svikramjeet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this battle ended.
I spent a lot of time with the support of Godaddy, Wix, DigitalOcean, Nominalia, and e.t.c.
As I wrote on my question, I found that the issue was with the DS record that I can't delete. In the end, I disconnected my domain name from any external services, configured Godaddy (this is my registrar), bought Godaddy hosting (just to set up all only in Godaddy environment). But still, I had the same issue. I called Godaddy and said that my domain name registered there, my hosting in the same place, but still, my web page (I created one) was not propagated after 5 days.
Godaddy just reset all domain settings and now it works!
Hope this description can help somebody to save a lot of time.